# SSRS 2019 PDF export issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

Getting the following error while exporting SSRS report to PDF. Excel export is working fine. Only issue with PDF. Any help on this issue would be welcome.

```
RenderFromSession('/Test/TestReport')
reportrendering!ReportServer_0-12 e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.TextRun.ShapeAndPlace(Win32DCSafeHandle hdc, FontCache fontCache)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.LineBreaker.GetLine(Paragraph paragraph, TextLine line, Win32DCSafeHandle hdc, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext, Single left, Single right, Single height, Stack`1 lineRunsIndex, Stack`1 lineRunsCharIndex, Int32 lineIndents)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.LineBreaker.FlowParagraph(Paragraph paragraph, Directions direction, Win32DCSafeHandle hdc, Single dpiX, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext, Boolean keepLines, SizeF flowContextSize, Int32& contentOffset)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.LineBreaker.Flow(TextBox textBox, Win32DCSafeHandle hdc, Single dpiX, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext, Boolean keepLines, Single& height)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.LineBreaker.Flow(TextBox textBox, Graphics g, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext, Boolean keepLines, Single& height)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.TextBox.MeasureFullHeight(TextBox textBox, Graphics g, FontCache fontCache, FlowContext flowContext, Single& contentHeight)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.TextBox.CalculateVerticalSize(PageContext pageContext)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.TextBox.DetermineVerticalSize(PageContext pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, Boolean hasUnpinnedAncestors)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItem.CalculateVertical(PageContext pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem, PageItem[] siblings, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, Boolean hasUnpinnedAncestors, Nullable`1 sourceWidth)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItemContainer.DetermineContentVerticalSize(PageContext pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, Boolean hasUnpinnedAncestors, Boolean resolveState, Boolean resolveItem)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HPBProcessing.PageItemContainer.DetermineVerticalSize(PageContext pageContext, Double topInParentSystem, Double bottomInParentSystem, List`1 ancestors, Boolean& anyAncestorHasKT, B
library!ReportServer_0-/11/2024-11:13:44:: e ERROR: Report server dump occured. Exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component., Message: , Unhandled Exception: False
library!ReportServer_0-/11/2024-11:13:44:: e ERROR: Report server unique dump occured. Exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component., Message: , Unhandled Exception: False
library!ReportServer_0-/11/2024-11:13:50:: i INFO: Dump result: External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.
```

Any help on this issue would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you investigated the possible issues listed here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/89da0b24-a74a-4e8b-ba6b-c39146dc1cd9/rrrenderingerror-error-while-exporting-report-to-pdf?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Yes we investigated . The same report is working in dev sever but not working in prod server

Comment: If you have investigated you need to add the details if what things you have tried to the question.

Comment: Does the report use a custom font that's installed on the dev server but not on the prod server?